# How do i set tab icon using "Vaadin Frame work of java" for my website so it shows up in my web browser?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Using "Vaadin Frame work of java" How do i set tab icon for my website so it shows up in my web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a theme for your application and put favicon.ico in the root of your theme folder (e.g. VAADIN/themes/mytheme/favicon.ico). More information about Vaadin themes can be found from Book of Vaadin ([Vaadin 6](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/themes.html) or [Vaadin 7](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html)).